# MongoDB Endpoints Not Working on Heroku, but Functioning Locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I'm currently facing an issue with my MongoDB endpoints on Heroku, and I'm seeking assistance to diagnose the problem. I've developed a Node.js application using Express.js and MongoDB, and I've encountered a situation where the endpoints involving the database are not returning data on Heroku, while they function as expected in my local environment.

To provide more context:

-I've whitelisted the necessary IP addresses in the MongoDB Atlas database.
-All required environment variables have been correctly configured both locally and on Heroku.
-The main endpoint, which doesn't interact with the database, operates correctly both locally and on Heroku.
-When I access the endpoints that retrieve data from the database on Heroku, I'm not encountering any -apparent errors. However, the responses consist of an empty list "[]" for list-based queries and "null" for single value queries.

Here is an example of one of the endpoint implementations that retrieve data from the database:

```
export const getAllCharacters = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const characters = await Character.find()
        res.status(200).json(characters)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message })
    }
}
```

Despite no apparent errors being thrown, if I try to log console.log(characters) in the code above, it returns an empty list "[]". It's important to note that everything is functioning properly locally, including the routes, controllers, middleware, etc.

I've thoroughly reviewed the log messages both on Heroku and in my system console, and there are no error indications reported.

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.